# Firebase Crashlytics not generating crash report for release APKs Android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, release-apk

After integrating Firebase Crashlytics in app, am not receiving the crash report in Firebase Crashlytics dashboard for release builds. For debug builds I am restricting to generate the report and only generating the report for release builds.

App level build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

  buildTypes {
        def enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild = false
        def enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild = true

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInDebugBuild}"]
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_signing
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled:"${enableCrashlyticsInReleaseBuild}"]
        }
    }

dependencies {
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Project level build.gradle file

```
 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2"
                 }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}" />
```

Can anyone please suggest me where I am wrong? After checked all the SO answers didn't find out any solution.

Comment: I tried using the same variables and it worked for me. It would be interesting to see the in the debug logs if this line is present " Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled manifest flag." or if something else could be blocking Crashlytics. Check this document on how to get debug logs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging